# RDP connections not working to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp

EC2 will not accept RDP connections. On windows, I am using RDP to connect to my EC2 windows instance. But on the step where I see "configuring session..." , a second or two later the connection is terminated.  Why is this happening? It was working a few hours ago.

Comment: Is remote desktop enabled on the EC2 machine you are connecting to?

Comment: Well, restarted the instance. Went fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had two times problems with connecting RDP to EC2

1) The first time I contacted Amazon Support and they told me they had a problem with the underlying hardware (although the portal gave a green running status). They advised me to restore my own backups. Weird enough, it worked again after a few days. I think it was a network issue.

2) I just rebooted the EC2 machine several times (like 4) and then I worked again.

I experienced issues with VPN products from LogMeIn Hamachi and Kerio VPN. Make an appropriate backup before you install this software.